# How to optimize a spatial query?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, spatial-query

I need to optimize this query, 'coz execution time is too long. I've built gist indexes on geom(point), but they are not used unfortunaly.

```
    select *, cast(st_distance_sphere(city_gis.point, tmp1.pnt) as int) as distance
        from tmp1
    inner join  city_gis
     on cast(st_distance_sphere(city_gis.point,tmp1.pnt) as int) between 0 and 60000
```

[Here my query and execution plan](http://i017.radikal.ru/1403/2e/13c2eaebdec7.jpg)

Comment: I'm guessing that `city_gis.point` is of type `geometry(Point,4326)`, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ST_DISTANCE` functions do not use a geometry index. You should use e.g. `ST_DWITHIN` so your query would be something like

```
select *, cast(st_distance_sphere(city_gis.point, tmp1.pnt) as int) as distance
from tmp1
inner join city_gis on st_dwithin(city_gis.point,tmp1.pnt,60000)
```

Here is the documentation of this function.

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html

Comment: Well, i try this, but it doesn't help me: the execution time still the same =(

Comment: Do you have geometry indexes on both geom columns? Maybe the database query plan works in the other direction.

Comment: Yes, i'm sure that geom indexes are on both geom col-s.

Comment: Could you provide a execution plan for this query? PgAdmin does provide for this a user interface.

Comment: Unfortunately, the units of measure for `st_dwithin` are in degrees, not meters.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table called `city_gis`, I'm going to assume that this is a table of GIS data for a city. Is it one city, or more? If it is geographically isolated, make life much easier by using a projected coordinate system for the region. You can always transform coordinates back to lat/long for other uses. By using a projected coordinate system, any distance-related functions will use the projected units. For example, when using a UTM coordinate system, the distance units are always in metres. Obviously, this wouldn't work if your table indeed contains data from different cities across the world, or even in one continent.

Comment: No, there are many cities in this table (>30 000). I've called it so because it comfortable for me. Columns in this table: city_id, city, country, lat, lon.